# Alter Queryset before returning in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model structure similar to the one below:

**Store** -> some store fields

**Books** -> some book fields, FK to Store

**BookProperty** -> name, value, FK to Books (a one to many relationship), FK to store

The book property can store any info for the book eg. no_of_pages, publisher etc added by the store.

I need to make an API endpoint where I can get all BookProperty for a store.
I used the url:

`/stores/:store_id/bookproperty`

Used a ModelSerializer for BookProperty with `fields = [publisher, no_of_pages]`
Used a genericViewSet with a ListModelMixin.

The endpoint turned out like this below:

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "publisher",
            "value": "somePublisher"
        },
        {
            "name": "pages",
            "value": "1000"
        },
        {
            "name": "publisher",
            "value": "someOtherPublisher"
        },
        {
            "name": "publisher",
            "value": "somePublisher"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem with this is that multiple objects can have the same name, value pairs. I need this information in a way where all the objects are unique and grouped kind of like this:

```
{
{"name":"publisher", "value":["somePublisher", "someOtherPublisher"]},
{"name":"pages", "value":["1000"]},
}
```

I'm trying to override the `get_queryset(self)` but it's not working.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

models.py

```
class BookProperty(models.Model):
    books = models.ForeignKey(
        Books,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store = models.ForeignKey(
        "Store",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

serializers.py

```
class BookPropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.BookProperty
        fields = ["name", "value"]
```

views.py

```
class BookPropertyViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.BookPropertySerializer
```

I think that instead of overriding the `get_queryset(self)` I should try changing the `def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` :

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        tag_dictionary = defaultdict()
        things = list(queryset)
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(things, lambda x: x.name):
            for thing in group:
                if key not in tag_dictionary.keys():
                    tag_dictionary[key] = [thing.value]
                else:
                    tag_dictionary[key].append(thing.value)
        for key in tag_dictionary.keys():
            tag_dictionary[key] = list(set(tag_dictionary[key]))

        return Response(json.dumps(tag_dictionary))
```

The above solution is working but might not be the best one.

Comment: You haven't showed us any code, but `get_queryset` is the way to go.

Comment: can you show your model and serializer